# vb.net retrieve items from Listview on SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to get the value from a listview in vb.net, but keep getting an error of:

**'SelectedItem' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView'.**

I think I need to change eventargs to some other event type, but am struggling with this. Could someone please point out my error. Thanks

```
Sub filllistview()
        Try
            'creatconn()
            cn.Open()
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select * from Customers", cn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While dr.Read()
                ListView1.Items.Add(dr(0).ToString())
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(1))

            End While

        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            dr.Close()
            cn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Need to catch here

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            showcontectsinlistview()
            str = ListView1.SelectedItem **<--- ERROR**

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true beacuse it doesn't exist a "SelectedItem" property.
The ListView object has a property "SelectedItems", that is a collection. So you could use something like: `listView1.SelectedItems[0].`

With this you will have the first of the selected items in the collection given by the "SelectedItems" property. To navigate through all the selected items, you can loop between them in this way:

```
For Each itm As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
If itm.Selected Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To itm.SubItems.Count - 1
        str += itm.SubItems(i).Text
    Next
End If
Next
```

In this way you build a string with all the values of all the selected items. If you have only 1 selected item in the listview, you will have only that value.

Comment: I edit the answer. And, while we are here, explain what type of variable is " str ", thanks.

Comment: Dim str As String = Nothing. Thanks

Comment: Your latest code produces error: Cannot be converted to string

Comment: So, try in this way: ListView1.SelectedValue.ToString()

Comment: 'SelectedValue' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView'

Comment: So in the end I'm pretty sure you have to use ListView1.SelectedItems[0].text. It works?

Comment: Yes it does work, but how do I get sub items. Thanks

Comment: I modify my code to have all the values from all the subitems of any selected item of your listview. Try it and let me know :)

Comment: This code shows lots of errors such as: no matching next, ) expected no end if and syntax errors. Thanks

Comment: Sorry my fault, i wrote it in c# :-) . Now I translated it in VB.Net

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example

```
 Private Sub lstDirectoryInfo_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstDirectoryInfo.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim str As String = String.Empty

    For Each itm As ListViewItem In lstDirectoryInfo.SelectedItems
        If itm.Selected Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To itm.SubItems.Count - 1
                str = itm.SubItems(i).Text
            Next
        End If
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(str)
End Sub
```